# Best way to rewrite lines in text file with rounded values

Tags: python, file, text, rounding

I have a text file with multiple lines. Each line has values separated with spaces  :

```
0.004061345 0.02444009 -0.02234149 -0.01368116 0.02479915 5.76696e-012
```

I am looking for the best way to rewrite the same text file but with rounded values in it:

```
0.004 0.024 -0.022 -0.014 0.025 0.000
```

What would be the most Pythonic way?

```
Here is my solution, a combinaison of PepperoniPizza and Jan Vlcinsky
```

Code:

```
stringNewFile = ''
i = 0 #-- My file as a header that I need to keep untouch

with open('myfile.txt', 'rb') as fin:
for line in fin.readlines():
    stringNewFile = stringNewFile + line if i < 6 else stringNewFile + " ".join(map(lambda itm: "{0:.3f}".format(float(itm)), line.split()))+'\n'
    i = i + 1


file_handle = open('myfile.txt', 'w')
file_handle.write(stringNewFile)
file_handle.close()
```

Cheers!

Comment: Do you have any code yet? Show us what you have so far. The premise of the program is: read in the file, split the line on each space, convert the string to a number, round the number, convert the numbers back into one long string, and write the string back to the file. Try doing each of those steps individually and then put them together.

Comment: I would probably read the file line by line and then split that line by spaces into a list. I would then iterate through each element of the list and turn the string into a float value. Then you can call the `round` function which will then round the float. After that you can just rewrite it back into the file

Answer (score 1):

Read each line, split line into separate strings, convert each string into a float and round it, then write to a new file.

```
fout = open('rounded.txt', 'wb')

with open(input, 'rb') as fin:
    for line in fin.readlines():
        values = line.split()
        for val in values:
            new_val = round(float(val), 3) # 3 digit precision
            fout.write(new_val)
            fout.write(' ')
        fout.write('\n')

fout.close()
```

Comment: you forgot a quotation mark in the first line and it is throwing the coloring off.

Comment: @Elias - rounding the number to 3 digit precision does not ensure, it will get printed that way. In some cases you will see small differences due to way, numbers are represented internally. But in most cases it will go fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the CSV library with space as a delimiter, something like this:

```
import csv

def test():
    out_csv_file = open('output.csv', 'w')
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as in_csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(in_csv_file, delimiter=' ')
        writer = csv.writer(out_csv_file, delimiter=' ')
        for row in reader:
            line_buffer = []
            for item in row:
                line_buffer.append(round(float(item), 3))
            writer.writerow(line_buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortly (reformatting the line):

```
>>> textin = "0.004061345 0.02444009 -0.02234149 -0.01368116 0.02479915 5.76696e-012"
>>> " ".join(map(lambda itm: "{:5.3f}".format(float(itm)), textin.split()))
'0.004 0.024 -0.022 -0.014 0.025 0.000'
```

Step by step:

```
>>> textin = "0.004061345 0.02444009 -0.02234149 -0.01368116 0.02479915 5.76696e-012"
>>> textin.split()
['0.004061345',
 '0.02444009',
 '-0.02234149',
 '-0.01368116',
 '0.02479915',
 '5.76696e-012']
>>> num = 3.141516
>>> "{:5.3f}".format(num)
'3.142'
>>> map(lambda itm: "{:5.3f}".format(float(itm)), textin.split())
['0.004', '0.024', '-0.022', '-0.014', '0.025', '0.000']
>>> " ".join(map(lambda itm: "{:5.3f}".format(float(itm)), textin.split()))
'0.004 0.024 -0.022 -0.014 0.025 0.000'
```

Applying to file conversion:

```
infile = "input.txt"
outfile = "output.txt"
with open(infile) as f_in, open(outfile, "w") as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        line = line.strip("\n") #remove trainilg newline, if present
        line = " ".join(map(lambda itm: "{:5.3f}".format(float(itm)), textin.split()))
        f_out.write(line + "\n")
```

Note: do not attempt to read and write the same file at once, it is too difficult.

Comment: Thanks. I went with your solution. It works well. See my post for my code example.